# Is it possible to set metadata on a MPEG2 video file?

Tags: linux, video, command-line, metadata, mp4

I have a whole pile of MPEG2 and MP4 files. I want to add metadata to the files, such as title, author, year, etc. I can use [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) to add this information to MP4 files, but I can't see how to do this with MPEG2 files. Is this possible? If so, are there any linux FLOSS command line tools to add this data?

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg should do the trick in Linux:

```
ffmpeg -metadata title="TITLE" -metadata artist="ARTIST" -metadata date=DATE -metadata genre="GENRE" -metadata comment="COMMENT" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -i old.avi new.avi
```

I found this on a thread on an [Arch Linux discussion board](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=43048).

UPDATE: I should point out that this is not a perfect solution since you're not actually adding or editing metadata to the existing file but making a duplicate of the file with the specified metadata. Not an ideal "solution," but it's the best I've found so far.